# object has no clean_data attribute Django

Tags: python, django

So I have been working on my first Django project and I have run into an issue I cannot figure out. When I run my dev server I get the following error:

```
AttributeError at /register/
'RegistrationForm' object has no attribute 'clean_data'
```

I have browsed the forums with little luck.
Here is the code:

Views Page:

```
def register_page(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.clean_data['username'],
            password=form.clean_data['password1'],
            email=form.clean_data['email'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form})
    return render_to_response(
        'registration/register.html',
        variables
        )
```

Forms page:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password (Again)',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput()
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password (Again)',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput()
    )

    def clean_password2(self):
        if 'password1' in self.clean_data:
            password1 = self.clean_data['password1']
            password2 = self.clean_data['password2']
            if password1 == password2:
                return password2
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.clean_data['username']
        if not re.search(r'^\w+$', username):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Username can only contain'
                                        'alphanumeric characters and the underscore.')
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError('Username is already taken.')
```

Thanks,
Seth

Comment: try with `cleaned_data`

Comment: Worked great...this community is awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mispelled the name of the attribute. Use `cleaned_data` instead.